# Can't create specific button in Xaml List view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a button which has the text "User Requests" in a list view, and once I click on it I would like it to filter some specific elements from a different list.

The code I have so far does not even display the button in the view, let alone have the desired functionality.

This is what I have so far. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```
<ListView 
   ItemsSource="{Binding UserRequests}"  
   SelectionMode="Single"  
   Width="Auto"   
   ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource listViewSingleClick}" 
   mvvm:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding ViewOrder}" 
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Custom Filters" Width="170">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text=" {Binding UserRequests}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I don't see your button element in this code. Can you complete your question with the relevant code ?

Comment: Instead of the $TextBlock there should have been a button there. This is what I had:       <Button Content="User Requests" Command="{Binding Path=UserRequests}"
                                        DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" />

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment by sk_ said, there are numerous possible issues with the code you presented, such as possibly faulty data binding, and not actually having a button control.

I'll just present you with some sample code, hopefully this will enable you to add the desired functionality to your own code. Please keep in mind that this is just how I'd satisfy the requirement and this is not the only way to to this.

**ViewModel(s):**

```
public class UserRequest : BaseViewModel  {

    public String Text { get; set; }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    public UserRequest()
    {
        Command = new RelayCommand(ActionToExecute);
    }

    public void ActionToExecute()
    {
        //Doing stuff here!
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<UserRequest> UserRequests { get; set; }  

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        UserRequests = new ObservableCollection<UserRequest>();
        UserRequests.Add(new UserRequest() {Text = "Test1"});
        UserRequests.Add(new UserRequest() { Text = "Test2" });
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel just implements INotifyPropertychanged. RelayCommand is a helper class that can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/quick-start-scenarios/wpf/quickstart-wpf-viewmodelbase-and-relaycommand). We need the Command Property in order to bind an action to the button click. In the constructor to SomeViewModel we just add some items to our list (so we actually see something in the View).

**MainWindow.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public SomeViewModel SomeViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow() {
        SomeViewModel = new SomeViewModel();
        DataContext = SomeViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

For simplicity I set the DataContext in the MainWindows code-behind. Feel free to set the data context some different way if you prefer.

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding UserRequests}"  
    SelectionMode="Single"  
    Width="Auto"   
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Custom Filters" Width="170">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Command="{Binding Command}" Content="{Binding Text}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Here I removed some lines (such as ViewOrder) for simplicity. This will result in a list view containing buttons (with the text defined in SomeViewModel). Clicking on one of those buttons will result in the ActionToExecute method being executed.